# SQL Top(2) of a secondary Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query

```
SELECT PR.WBS1, PR.WBS2 FROM PR
```

It brings back what I need, but want to limit to the top (2) of the WBS2 for each of the WBS1's.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Hint:  `top (2)` . . . `order by pr.wbs2`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. I need all the WBS1's, there are about 40.

Comment: . . Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a better description of what you want to do.

Comment: ... so you want the rows with the top 2 WBS2 *for each* WBS1 ...? If so, then what database are you using?

Comment: Exactly and MS SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql). 
It groups the based on WBS1 and then selects two from each group.

```
;WITH CTE AS (

    SELECT 
        PR.WBS1, 
        PR.WBS2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY PR.WBS1 ORDER BY PR.WBS2) AS RN
    FROM 
        PR
)

SELECT 
    WBS1,
    WBS2 
FROM 
    CTE 
WHERE 
    RN <=2
```

Comment: Much easier to implement with the additional requirements that I have. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT PR.WBS1, PR.WBS2 
FROM PR 
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM PR p
    WHERE p.WBS1 = PR.WBS1 
      AND p.WBS2 >= PR.WBS2
) <= 2;
```

Comment: There was an error in your first where clause, it got me to where I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is an error in the first where clause. It says p.WBS1 = p.WBS1, it should have been p.WBS1 = PR.WBS1.

Comment: sorry, fixed the typo

Answer (score 2):

I had to change a few things on the above answer.

```
SELECT PR.WBS1, PR.WBS2 
FROM PR 
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM PR p
    WHERE p.WBS1 = PR.WBS1 
      AND p.WBS2 <= PR.WBS2
) <= 2;
```